# remesh a certain region of a mesh rather than the whole mesh

Tags: sculpting

I would like to remesh the eyeballs to a significantly finer detail so that I can apply the crease brush. I attempted the remesh modifier but it appears to apply the refinement to all of the mesh...and also the crease brush does not do anything.
Is there a setting I am missing?

[image]

Comment: you could use a simple Draw brush with a Strength of 0 and Dyntopo enable, but why don't you simply enable Dyntopo and use the brush you want?

Comment: @moonboots. thanks. I used the 2nd option for this new model. My first model was too big poly wise that the tool was not responding.